# Arrange program windows out of bash script?

Tags: bash, shell, ubuntu

I'm writing a shell script to automatically launch my work environment. It would be pretty nice to arrange the program windows automatically (for example vim opens at the left on desktop, and browser opens at the right...)

Is it possible to give commands "window-parameters"?

I use Gnome on Ubuntu, if that matters.

Comment: You would look into something called `devilspie`. I'm not sure if it's available for your specific distro (as you did not state what distro you are using), but it could accomplish this.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's `devilspie2` now. (`devilspie` is not maintained now)

Please follow this [link](http://www.gusnan.se/devilspie2/)) to get the tool & related info.

If you are on Ubuntu then click [here](https://help.ubuntu.com/community/Devilspie)

For man page click [here](http://linux.die.net/man/1/devilspie)